# Count number of ways to construct binary search tree with n elements

Tags: python, tree

I had this question asked in an interview:

> In how many ways, we can construct binary search tree from \$n\$ elements?

I have written this code, but got a feedback that it could be improved. How to do it?

```
def count_ways(n):
    c = [0] * (n+1)
    c[0] = 1
    c[1] = 1
    for i in xrange(2, n+1):
        sum_w = 0
        for j in xrange(0, i):
            sum_w += c[j] * c[i-j-1]
        c[i] = sum_w
    return c[n]    


print count_ways(4)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The number of trees can be expressed in the closed form \$\frac{\binom{2n}{n}}{n+1}\$, and due to \$\binom{2n}{n} = \frac{4n - 6}{n} \binom{2(n-1)}{n-1}\$ the result is computed in linear time.

I would not ask such question in face-to-face interview (unless the position requires in-depth knowledge of combinatoric and graph theory).

Comment: Nice! Do you have a link to the explanation of the closed form?

Answer (score 2):

The only optimization obvious to me is to reduce the number of iterations in the inner loop by the factor of two:

```
def count_ways_v2(n):
    c = [0] * (n + 1)
    c[0] = 1
    c[1] = 1
    for i in range(2, n + 1):
        sum_w = 0
        for j in xrange(0, i / 2):
            sum_w += 2 * c[j] * c[i - j- 1]
        if i % 2 == 1:
            sum_w += c[i / 2] * c[i / 2] # Handle the case in which i is odd:
        c[i] = sum_w
    return c[n]
```

Hope it helps.

**Edit**

[@Peilonrayz](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/42401/peilonrayz) suggests an improvement: your and mine versions run in quadratic time, yet via [Catalan numbers](https://oeis.org/A000108) you can do it in linear time:

```
def count_ways_catalan(n):
    a, b = 1, 1
    for k in range(2, n + 1):
        a *= n + k
        b *= k
    return a / b
```

Comment: Better yet, use `math.factorial`. The formula is \$\frac{(2n)!}{(n+1)!n!}\$.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a slightly optimized version:

```
# python's default stack size is small
from sys import setrecursionlimit
setrecursionlimit((1<<31)-1)

def ways(n, cache={}):
    if n == 0: return 1
    elif n not in cache:
        cache[n] = sum(ways(s) * ways(n-s-1) for s in xrange(n))
    return cache[n]
```